# Needs debugging symbols for __alignof__

Tags: c, gdb, glibc

I'm debugging the glibc library. I've built it with -g3 -O flags. I can print most macros, but not this one. I'm debugging malloc(), and there are a lot of macros that use __alignof__. But I can't find its definition anywhere in glibc source code. Here is an example:

```
(gdb) p MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK
No symbol "__alignof__" in current context.
```

And also I got the same problem with __builtin_offsetof. But this one is an built in macro. So the 2 cases are a bit different. Solving this problem will speed up my debugging a bit.

Comment: Both [`__builtin_offsetof()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html) and [`__alignof__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alignment.html) are provided by GCC.

Comment: So, I'll have to rebuild gcc to get those symbols, last time it takes more than 1 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get any debugging information. Since `__alignof__` is, like `sizeof`, *only known at compile-time*. See [alignof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types) from `<stdalign.h>`

Even by recompiling GCC itself, you won't get it (there is *no* debugging information available). `__alignof__` is processed *at compile time* (so `__alignof__ (double)` is replaced by 8 during compilation, for x86-64 ABI).

You could guess by yourself the expanded value of `MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK`.

You could define a `const int my_malloc_align_mask = MALLOC_ALIGN_MASK;` and use  `p my_malloc_align_mask` in the debugger.

> I'm debugging the glibc library.

This is weird. You should *trust* the `glibc` library to behave as documented (yes, beware of *undefined behavior*).

Comment: Some background info: Very recently (September 2018) released GDB version 8.2 and later do understand `_Alignof`, which is equivalent to `__alignof__`; then, `macro define __alignof__ _Alignof` suffices in GDB.  GDB already supports `sizeof`. `__builtin_offsetof(type, member)` can be defined in GDB as `macro define __builtin_offsetof(t, f) ((unsigned long)(&((t *)0)->f)))`.

Comment: Thank you Basile. Actually, I want to study the internals of malloc(), e.g. how chunks of memories are allocated. Using the debugger to step through the code is a good way to do this.

Comment: That should go into your question: you are not debugging `libc`  but trying to understand it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NominalAnimal but there's one extra parenthesis at the end for `__builtin_offsetof`. It should be `macro define __builtin_offsetof(t, f) ((unsigned long)(&((t *)0)->f))`

Answer (score 2):

GDB only has a very approximate implementation of C and C++.  It does not use the same C and C++ parser as GCC, so some things are missing, including this GCC extension.  GDB recognizes `_Alignof`, but it is not exactly the same as `__alignof__`.  But it will work in this case, so you could change the glibc sources to use it.

LLDB uses the Clang parsers and therefore does not suffer from this particular problem, but will not help you here because apparently, the debugger does not recognize the DWARF data generated by the `-g3` option, so the macro information is missing from the executable.